# Force trusted foreign key SQL Server to allow join culling in view

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, datamart

I'm trying to create a star schema view of fact to it's dimension.

eg.

if the view is

```
Select  
    _fact.A, _Dim.B
from 
    _fact
inner join 
    _dim on _Fact.dim_sk = _dim.Dim_sk
```

and I query

```
Select _Fact.A 
from _view
```

It will ignore the join in the `_dim` .

One way of doing this is to create trusted foreign keys to the dimension.
However this means I have to create and enable check constraints which will slow down my inserts.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/do-foreign-keys-matter-for-insert-speed/

1. Is there a better way to allow join culling in a view?
2. Is there a way to force SQL server to mark foreign keys as trusted?

e.g. something along the lines of

```
update sys.foreign_keys
set is_not_trusted = 0
```

Comment: Have you checked the plan to make sure it's actually doing the join?  Also, why are you not just selecting from the table if this is a concern?  I think there's missing info in the question/

Comment: Hi the view is for the purpose of BI visualtion tool such Tableau/PowerBI. It seems with lots of joins ( 100+ ) it bring tableau to a crawl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you really may want enforced FKs in your schema.  You can disable them and check them at the end of your ETL if you want, and they are useful.

At some scale, however, you want to leave the FKs as NOCHECK for performance.

So the alternative is to use a LEFT JOIN, and then so long as the DIM table has a unique index on the join column, SQL knows that the join can't change the cardinality of the result, and will eliminate the join if don't reference the dimension columns.  eg:

```
    use tempdb

    go

    drop table if exists _fact 
    drop table if exists _dim
    go
    create table _dim(Dim_sk int primary key, B int)

    create table _fact( A int, dim_sk int references _dim)

    go

    create or alter view _view
    as
    Select  
        _fact.A, _Dim.B
    from 
        _fact
    left join 
        _dim on _Fact.dim_sk = _dim.Dim_sk

    go
    set statistics io on
    go
    Select A 
    from _view
    go
    set statistics io off
```

outputs

```
Table '_fact'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: Thanks David, I can confirm changing it to left join on a PK or unique index does cull the Join as a better way of doing things then creating FK constraints for my need.

Comment: Note that having FKs in a DW is definitely a best practice as they provide metadata to the users.  The question is whether to enforce them.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I disagree, slightly, that FKs are a best practice. Let's not forget that Microsoft's premier DW platforms - SQL Server Parallel Data Warehouse, and Azure SQL Data Warehouse - don't support them.

Comment: That PDW and SQL DW don't support unenforced FKs is a technical limitation, not a statement of best practices.   Enforced FKs are undeniably useful, but for a very large database may not be worth the cost.